# PHP session changes if variable changes

Tags: php, session

I have encountered a weird situation:

First I assign variable to a session then I change it. Then the session changes when I change the variable, even when I didn't re-assign the value to the session :

the example (session1.php)

```
session_start();
$var_test = "first session value";
$_SESSION['var_test'] = $var_test;
echo "$_SESSION['var_test'];

// this will show "first session value"
```

the second php file (session2.php)

```
session_start();
$var_test = "second session value !!!";
echo $_SESSION['var_test'];

// this shows "second session value !!!";
```

In session1.php it shows "first session value" which is perfectly good, but in the second php file (session2.php) it shows "second session value".

Even though I didn't assign $_SESSION['var_test'] = $var_test, how come does it change automatically?

Is that a bug or is it just how it works?

Comment: cannot reproduce your case. Your code works fine here.

Comment: And what happens if you *don't* change the variable? Just curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could probably be caused by register_globals=on in php ini. (If you are using an old php version)

try this in your .htaccess file (located in document root):

```
php_flag register_globals off.
```

(Our if you have access: change it in php.ini);

register_globals is a security threat for a bad written php application.

Comment: I think you are right, my register_globals is currently set as "ON" and I'm using php 5.2.6

Comment: Im bit scared if I change it to "OFF" it might crush my entire site as I dont know how will it affect all my pages ... :(

Comment: You should realy consider to turn it off! But when you do: test your applications since there could be some side effects for your curent scripts if they are poorly written.

Comment: You could always turn it back on!

Comment: Glad I could be of help!